# Disabling a cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

I use the above code to disable a cell after a user clicks on it once. The problem I've run into is that when a cell is added to the table, that new cell is disabled, and the previously disabled one isn't anymore.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`?

Comment: @fannheyward because I don't want that cell to be usable after being clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

Cells get reused as the user scrolls the table. You need to keep track of which rows the user has disabled so in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set the `userInteractionEnabled` property (to YES or NO as needed) for every cell every time it is requested.

Update - more details.

You need to keep track of which index paths the user has selected. Add an instance variable of type `NSMutableSet` and add each `indexPath` to this in your `didSelectRow...` method.

Then in your `cellForRow...` method you need to check if the current `indexPath` is in the set or not. Based on the result you set the cell's `userInteractionEnabled` property:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = ![theSelectedPathsSet containsObject:indexPath];
```

where `theSeletedPathsSet` is your `NSMutableSet` instance variable.

This solution assumes the rows and sections in your table are fixed. If the user can do things that results in rows being added, removed, or moved, then you can't simply track the index paths. You need to use some other key to know which rows have been selected.

Comment: Please explain where to put what better... I'm really confused. I already have a cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and when I make the cells enabled in that, then the disabling code doesn't do anything.

Comment: The user can do things like adding rows.

Comment: Then you need to track another another key, not the `indexPath` of each selected row. What that might be is up to you and your data.

Comment: @JacobBrubaker Thanks. If it answers your question don't forget to accept it (or at least upvote it).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

You should have something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"myTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
      cell = [[ArticleTableViewCell alloc] init];
}
// customise cell here (like cell.title = @"Woopee";)
if (self.selectedCells containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]] {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
return cell;
}
```

Expanding on the other answer, you can keep track of whether a specific cell has been previously selected (are therefore should be disabled) by doing something like this with the above:

Declare a property like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedCells;` then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.selectedCells addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

My laptop is about to die, but if it crashed you should look at the code the initialises the cell (alloc and init) or keep what you had before there.

Comment: How does this help answer the question? Where's the code to properly set the cell's `userInteractionEnabled` property based on whether the row has been selected or not?

Comment: No, I'm not quite sure where to put this... I already have a big cellforrowatindexpath method that if i put this in, the whole app crashes.

Comment: @scottastic - Your code will end up setting all rows to have no interaction. You need to turn `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` if the cell is not in the list of selected rows. Your code also only works if there is one section and if rows can't be added, removed, or moved.

Comment: @JacobBrubaker If you think this is too complicated then take a step back and do some reading about table views and maybe some basic Objective-C. There is nothing complicated about this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a record of which cells have been disabled. You could store the indexPath of the selected cells in an array and then use that to determine which cells should be active and not active in your cell:forRowAtIndexPath: method.